# How to show an Alert message to user when clicks or touches the seekbar of default Mediacontroller with videoview?

Tags: android, android-videoview, seekbar, mediacontroller

I am implemented **VideoView** with **Mediacontroller** like below.

```
MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(VideoViewActivity.this);
mediacontroller.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
mVideoView.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
```

Now I want to show an Alert When user clicks on seekbar.
I have tried with following code by adding `onclickListener` to seekbar, but not working.

```
int topContainerId = getResources().getIdentifier("mediacontroller_progress", "id", "android");
SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) mediacontroller.findViewById(topContainerId);
seekbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, "WE HAVE LIFT OFF");
            showAlertMesage();
           }
     });
```

But the event is not firing hence alert message with '**Ok**' and '**Cancel**' options not showing.

Also implementation should be showing an alert when user clicks/touches the seekbar.The seekbar need not to be seekable till user clicks 'OK'.

If user clicks 'Cancel' Video playing and seeking position should not be change. if clicks on 'Ok' it should be seekable to that postion.

So kindly please share or suggest How to implement this behaviour,  Thank you all in advance.

Comment: seekbar.setOnTouchListener(>)

Comment: Yes tried with onTouchListener,also, but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct. But you need to do it after your video is prepared.Make use of `OnPreparedListener`

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mVideoView.start();
                int topContainerId = getResources().getIdentifier("mediacontroller_progress", "id", "android");
                SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) mediacontroller.findViewById(topContainerId);
                 seekbar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                       Log.i(TAG, "WE HAVE LIFT OFF");
                         if(seekAllowed){ //declare seekAllowed as false globally
                             return false;
                          }
                        webView1.pause();
                        showAlertMesage();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Dialog:

```
private void showAlertMesage() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        seekAllowed = true;
                        webView1.resume();
                    }
                });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        webView1.resume();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, Its working , if get the seekbar object in onPrepared. Thank you Dhina,

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `onSeekChangeListener`

```
mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {                
                if(mMediaPlayer != null && fromUser){
                     Log.i(TAG, "WE HAVE LIFT OFF");
                    showAlertMesage();
                }
            }
    });
```

Comment: Tried with the above seekbar change listener not working.

Comment: I have a doubt that getting the Seekbar object from Mediacontroller is correct or not? if not how to get the object and assign the listener to it

Comment: @Ganesh yeah that could be be the reason.